Does geometric realization commute with finite limits?
I am trying to find out if geometric realizations i.e. the functor $|-|\colon\text{sSet}\to \text{Top}$ commutes with finite limits. In the following post the user claim that this is well known:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138908/geometric-realization-of-simplicial-spaces-and-finite-limits
However I am unable to find any reference or an argument to show that. Does anyone have an basic proof or can provide a reference? In particular I want to use this to see that $|\Omega X| \cong \Omega|X|$ where $X$ is an anima.

It is for instance shown here on the nLab. Note that we must assume $\mathrm{Top}$ is a convenient category of topological spaces, not the category of all topological spaces. Your statement about anima does not make much sense to me, because for me an anima is an object in the $\infty$-category $\mathcal{S}$ of spaces. If I let $\mathrm{sSet}_{\infty}$ and $\mathrm{Top}_\infty$ denote the underlying $\infty$-categories of the Kan model structure on simplicial sets and the Quillen model structure on a convenient category of topological spaces, then geometric realization gives an equivalence $|-|\colon\mathrm{sSet}_\infty\to\mathrm{Top}_\infty$ of $\infty$-categories (both these $\infty$-categories represent $\mathcal{S}$), and such an equivalence automatically preserves all limits in the $\infty$-category, so also loop objects. Using the terminology "anima" makes it sound to me that the statement you are trying to prove is $\Omega|X|\simeq|\Omega X|$, which is a tautology that does not need finite limit-preservation of geometric realization on the model categories.

why is the statement $\Omega|X|\simeq|\Omega X|$ a tautology?

Ah, I should be more precise here. If $X$ is an object in $\mathrm{sSet}\infty$ and $|-|$ is a functor $\mathrm{sSet}\infty\to\mathrm{Top}_\infty$, then it is not a tautology but it follows from the fact that $|-|$ is an equivalence of $\infty$-categories. If we identify both sides with $\mathcal{S}$, then $|-|$ corresponds to the identity functor on $\mathcal{S}$, and then for an anima $X\in\mathcal{S}$ the statement becomes $\Omega X\simeq \Omega X$, and this is a tautology.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is an $\infty$-category equivalent to $\mathcal{S}$, then this equivalence is unique, so we can safely just identify $\mathcal{C}$ with $\mathcal{S}$ and consider the equivalence we started with to be the identity on $\mathcal{S}$, so that's why in my head the statement $\Omega|X|\simeq|\Omega X|$ for $X\in\mathrm{sSet}\infty$ and $|-|\colon\mathrm{sSet}\infty\to\mathrm{Top}_\infty$ is also a tautology, but this is admittedly not truly a tautology.

If you mean "Kan complex" when you talk about an anima, then the statement becomes even more nontrivial, but for me a Kan complex (which is in particular an object in a $1$-category) and an anima (which is an object of the $\infty$-category $\mathcal{S}$) are different things, not in the least because the ambient $\infty$-categories are different. Also, there are many more point-set constructions you can perform with Kan complexes that are not meaningful anymore in anima, and an anima underlying a Kan complex even does not know anymore how many simplices your Kan complex had.

Thank you! this makes a lot of sense
